# Specify Typing of class with custom Metaclass

Tags: pycharm, metaclass, python-typing

Following on a great system for using an enum-like replacement for Django choices (http://musings.tinbrain.net/blog/2017/may/15/alternative-enum-choices/) I have a project that uses a class with a custom metaclass that allows me to do `list(MyChoices)` (on the Class itself) to get a list of all the enum choices.  The relevant part of the code looks something like this:

```py
class MetaChoices(type):
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(mcs, name, bases, **kwargs):
        return OrderedDict()

    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        _choices = OrderedDict()
        for attr_name, value in list(attrs.items()):
            ...do things...
        return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, dict(attrs))

    def __iter__(cls):
        return iter(cls._choices.items())


class Choices(metaclass=MetaChoices):
    pass

class IceCreamFlavor(Choices):
    STRAWBERRY = ('strawberry', 'Fruity')
    CHOCOLATE = 'chocolate'

list(IceCreamFlavor)
# [('strawberry', 'Fruity'), ('chocolate', Chocolate')
```

The code has been working well for some time, but now I have typing turned on (in this case using PyCharm's type checker, but also looking for general solutions), and `IceCreamFlavor` is not marked as an iterable despite it being derived from a class whose metaclass defines the `cls` as having an `__iter__` method.  Does anyone know of a solution where I can show that the `Choices` class itself is itself an iterable?

Comment: It's a bug in PyCharm's type checker, could you please file an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY?

Comment: @user2235698: I think that PyCharm could be not the right place to "file" it and it is probably an upstream issue of another package, but people at PyCharm can easily say which package is responsible. It is also not a bug, if docs of that package (MyPy?) specifies a boundary of limited support of metaclasses. This is usually solved first as an [extension plugin in MyPy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending_mypy.html) by get_metaclass_hook(), later maybe adopted and finally maybe also enabled by default.

Comment: @hynekcer PyCharm does not use mypy, it has its own type checker

Comment: @user2235698: A plugin [mypy-pycharm](https://github.com/leinardi/mypy-pycharm) exist for PyCharm that is written in Java and it calls a `mypy` executable. Yes, PyCharm has its own checker, but it does not mean that it doesn't use MyPy for typing in any case.

Comment: @hynekcer this plugin is not bundled, the only way to use it is to manually install through `File - Settings - Plugins`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the code to be correct for MyPy (checked easier by Pytype that adds annotation files *.pyi first).

A typing problem was in the method `__iter__()`, that the attribute `_choices` seems undefined for a checker, because it was assigned not transparently, only by `attrs['_choices'] = ...`.

It can be annotated by adding one line:

```py
class MetaChoices(type):
    _choices = None  # type: dict   # written as comment for Python >= 3.5
    # _choices: dict                # this line can be uncommented if Python >= 3.6
```

It is perfectly valid for [Pytype](https://google.github.io/pytype/) and with its annotations it is checked valid also by MyPY of course.

Maybe that typing problem in `__iter__()` could cause that the metaclass method was ignored in the checker.

---

If the fix doesn't help, then the issue can be reported with the following simplified example:

```py
class MetaChoices(type):
    _choices = {0: 'a'}

    def __iter__(cls):
        return iter(cls._choices.items())


class Choices(metaclass=MetaChoices):
    pass


assert list(Choices) == [(0, 'a')]
```

---

I reported another minor bug to the original article. That bug is not related to this problem.

Comment: `class Choices(Iterable, metaclass=MetaChoices)` does not work because a `Choices` object is in fact, not iterable, but only the Class itself is.

Comment: You are right. I simplified the answer. If it doesn't help then the tag 'mypy' is not relevant for this question.

Comment: Your version passes mypy, @hynekcer, so I'll remove the mypy tag.